Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established- nodejs app and aks node
I have nodejs application running on aks. 6 pods of the application are running. Application insight is configured in the aks. I am getting exception in app insights saying

FetchError: request to https://www.xxxxxxx.com/WebAPI/api/OJJ/Appointments/1 failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

We are getting this exception intermittently only. There will be no errors for 2-3 days, then this exception will come.
Exception occurred in last 7 days

For debugging the issue, I have done packet capture at aks node.

10.50.38.233 is the IP of the aks node.
192.168.19.160 is the IP of our load balancer. www.xxxxxxx.com is behind this LB and there is SSL offloading at LB also.

TLS v1.0 & v1.1 are disabled in LB, only TLS v1.2 and v1.3 are enabled.
Packet captured at aks node when we were getting frequent

Packet captured at aks node when there was no exception

Successful communications are happening on TLS v1.3 and all failed  communications are happening on either v1.0 or v1.1.
Question : How can we ensure that application will communicate only on TLS v1.2 or v1.3 with the server ?
Is it something needs to done from application code or  from container image or from aks node configuration.

In your Node.js application, you can specify the minimum and maximum TLS version directly in the HTTPS request options. This ensures that no connections are attempted using versions older than TLS v1.2. Here’s how you can modify your HTTPS requests. Something like this-

const options = {     hostname: 'www.example.com',     port: 443,     path: '/WebAPI/api/OJJ/Appointments/1',     method: 'GET',     secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method', // Only allow TLS v1.2     // For TLS v1.2 or v1.3, you might use minVersionandmaxVersion in newer Node versions:     // minVersion: 'TLSv1.2',     // maxVersion: 'TLSv1.3' };  Make sure your version of Node.js supports minVersion and maxVersion options if you choose to use them. These options are available in Node.js 10.0.0 and later.

To address the intermittent TLS issues, you're encountering with your Node.js application running in AKS, where successful communications are using TLS v1.3 but failures are occurring when older TLS versions are attempted, you can check out the below example-
Your question- Is it something needs to done from application code?
Yes, ensure that every HTTPS request initiated by your Node.js application specifies TLS v1.2 or v1.3. This can be done using the https module in Node.js, configuring the minVersion and maxVersion options.
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/api/data',
  method: 'GET',
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem'),
  minVersion: 'TLSv1.2', // Minimum version of TLS
  maxVersion: 'TLSv1.3'  // Maximum version of TLS
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

req.end();

Alternatively, you can configure the container image to use only TLS v1.2 or v1.3 by setting the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable to --tls-min-v1.2 or --tls-min-v1.3, respectively. Finally, you can configure the AKS node to only allow TLS v1.2 and v1.3 by modifying the Schannel-specific registry keys as described in the TLS 1.2 Upgrade Workflow article
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--tls-min-v1.2"

References:

Similar Thread

TLS min and max 

TLS: client offered only unsupported versions error on client when connecting to the AKS API server


